# How to set google maps background when the map has already been created. map.setOptions() does not work

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

I have set a dark background when creating a new google map. Turns out the background is being changed automatically when user changes to 'street mode'. So, when the user comes back to the 'normal mode' the background stays white.

I want to be able to change the background back to dark but it seems it setOptions() method does not work for 'background' property.

```
this.map.setOptions({
    backgroundColor: '#2D3339 !important'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions.backgroundColor) specifically states: "This option can only be set when the map is initialized"

> **backgroundColor** Type:  string
>   Color used for the background of the Map div. This color will be visible when tiles have not yet loaded as the user pans. **This option can only be set when the map is initialized.**